# How to get string representation of query for Oracle database in Python 2.7

Tags: python, sql, oracle, python-2.7, cx-oracle

I'm sending some prepared SQL statement and dictionary of variables for substitution using Python 2.7 to server for remote execution on Oracle Database.

I want to log final query, that will be executed on server, but can't find a way to get a string representation of final query.

Prepared statement example:

```
delete from my_table where col1=:date and col2=:string and col3=:num
```

Dictionary example:

```
{'date':datetime.datetime(2016, 3, 25, 0, 0), 'string':'abc', 'num':42}
```

What I want to get (whatever SQL, that could be executed and with my data):

```
delete from my_table where col1=TO_DATE('25-03-2016 00:00','dd-mm-yyyy hh24:mi') and col2='abc' and col3=42
```

Comment: There is no "final SQL" in Oracle with prepared statements - the values are not substituted in plain text form as you want. The prepared statement is executed with the parameters you pass in.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Still is there a way to generate this kind of SQL query? I think that somebody had written code for this already.

Comment: Why do you want this? Since that's not what gets executed, and you have to worry about quoting for it to be even realistic, it seems pointless. Just log the statement & the parameters if logging is the goal, that's the only way to reproduce the query accurately.

Comment: Probably, you are right. Maybe I was looking in the wrong direction. Thanks for sharing your ideas.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Why do you want this? Since that's not what gets executed, and you have to worry about quoting for it to be even realistic, it seems pointless. Just log the statement & the parameters if logging is the goal, that's the only way to reproduce the query accurately. – Mat Mar 28 at 16:07

Thanks to Mat for his comments.